# ¿Cómo obtener las estadísticas de Google Analytics en una hoja de cálculo de Google Docs?

Tags: api, google-api, google-analytics

He notado que en las hojas de cálculo de Google Docs hay un add-on que permite interactuar con la cuenta de Google Analytics para acceder a sus estadísticas y he seguido los pasos de la [guía](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) oficial de Google.

Una vez instalado el plugin y concedido a este el acceso a mi cuenta de Analytics tras solicitar la creación de un nuevo reporte me da el siguiente error:

```
"""
There's a problem

It looks like you don't have any Google Analytics
accounts with data.

Note: this add-on integrates with your existing Google
Analytics data. It is not a generic data analysis tool
for Google Sheets.

To learn more about Google Analytics, visit:
https://google.com/analytics.
"""
```

Y luego este otro:

```
"Error: User has no Google Analytics account data."
```

Pensé que era un problema de acceso pero luego vi que este add-on no requiere la configuración de la [API de Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4), ni de la creación de llaves de autenticación u otros sistemas similares.

Otra información relevante es que mi cuenta de Google Analytics fue creada hace solo dos días y no ha recogido muchos datos, pero ya he comprobado la existencia de los mismos.

¿Podría ser que necesito esperar más tiempo para que la cantidad de datos sea suficiente a satisfacer las "expectativas" del add-on o creen que se trata de un problema diferente?

> PD: Para aquellos que tengan curiosidad del porqué quiero conectar estos dos servicios, en el enlace de la guía pueden encontrar más información. Resumiendo, su utilidad es poder visualizar los datos de Google Analytics de forma gráfica en cualquier sitio web (incluido el sitio monitoreado).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si instalaste el Plugin, es muy importante asegurar que tu cuenta tenga permisos para consultar datos de Google Analytics para poder crear un reporte de la información de Google Analytics.

En el caso que expones el problema indica:

> "Error: User has no Google Analytics account data."

El problema no se debe a permisos, se debe a que no tienes información para generar el reporte, la información debe ser obtenida a partir de la vista de una propiedad.

Debes crear una propiedad:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10269537?ref_topic=1009620

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este punto debes elegir crear Create unicamente "Universal Analytics property" o "Google Analytics 4" y "Universal Analytics property". Esta sería la diferencia

> Las propiedades de "Google Analytics 4" combinan la medición de
> aplicaciones y web; por el contrario, las propiedades de "Universal
> Analytics property" se centran en la Web. Al asignar la recopilación
> de datos de "Universal Analytics property" a la recopilación de datos
> de "Google Analytics 4", tenga en cuenta las necesidades de medición
> de su aplicación.

[Diferencias entre los datos de Universal Analytics y Google Analytics 4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9964640?hl=es)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al crear la propiedad en tu cuenta, esta puede ser seleccionada para obtener el reporte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Como dije he creado una propriedad y tengo datos, pero no había activado la opción “universal analytics property” y no cuento con la opción “create view”. Probaré a crear una nueva propiedad con esa opción activada y te haré saber como va.

Comment: Super importante poder crear una vista ya que esta información es la precisamente se agrega al reporte. @ArielMontes

Comment: Me surgió una pregunta al seguir tus indicaciones y activar la opción “universal analyics property” me pregunta si deseo crear dos propiedades o solo una y no sé que es lo más conveniente o como puede afectarme a la larga.

Comment: Bueno lo que sucede es que si tienes solo un sitio web puedes solo seleccionar "Universal Analytics properties", en mi caso los proyectos que tengo son apps y sitios web entonces lo mejor es usar "Google Analytics 4 properties" y "Universal Analytics properties". Agregué esta información a la respuesta.

Comment: Genial, solucionaste mi problema. Te lo agradezco mucho!!

Comment: Excelente @ArielMontes saludos!